# Problem with OneToMany mapping and updates/deletes

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa-2.1

Running our application in Wildfly 14.0.1 connecting to a Postgres 11 DB.

I have two entities defined with the following:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(WorkingSetEntryId.class)
public class WorkingSetEntry implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String workingsetname;
    @Id
    private String handlename;
    @Id
    private String workingsettype;
    private Long handleid;
    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(WorkingSetId.class)
@Table(name="WORKINGSET")
public class WorkingSetDTO implements Comparable<WorkingSetDTO>, Serializable
{
   @Id
   private String name;
   @Id
   private String type;

   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumns({
           @JoinColumn(name="workingsetname", referencedColumnName = "name"),
           @JoinColumn(name="workingsettype", referencedColumnName = "type")
   })
   private List<WorkingSetEntry> entries;
   ...
}
```

When retrieving data, it works perfectly fine. All the fields for both parent and child are filled in.

However, when I try the following:

```
     EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
     WorkingSetDTO ws = em.createNamedQuery("WorkingSetDTO.findByNameAndType", WorkingSetDTO.class)
                .setParameter("name", wsId)
                .setParameter("type", wsType)
                .getSingleResult();
     em.remove(ws);
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "workingsetname" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, DV_POSTBURN_SCS_SIDEA, 0).
    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.6.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 132 more
```

I also can't update the entities with the following code:

```
     EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
     WorkingSetDTO ws = em.createNamedQuery("WorkingSetDTO.findByNameAndType", WorkingSetDTO.class)
                .setParameter("name", wsId)
                .setParameter("type", wsType)
                .getSingleResult();
     List<WorkingSetEntry> curEntries = current.getEntries();
     List<WorkingSetEntry> newEntries = workingSet.getEntries();
     curEntries.removeIf(e -> !newEntries.contains(e));
     curEntries.addAll(newEntries.stream().filter(e -> !curEntries.contains(e)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Without the following error:

```
EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.rsc.mmpl.dto.workingset.WorkingSetEntry#com.rsc.mmpl.dto.workingset.WorkingSetEntryId@5dbced55]
```

So apparently I'm doing something wrong even with a basic entity like that.  I have other entities that work perfectly fine, but they only have a single ID field associated with them so I'm guessing it's a misunderstanding I have with tables with multiple field IDs.

Any suggestions/pointers/help would be greatly appreciated.  I could always just generate a new single ID for each entity, but was trying to reuse existing code as much as possible without doing schema updates, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this just by generating an ID and populating that to the children once persisted, works fine.  I also fixed the list update a bit to make sure I EntityManager.remove children that no longer are part of the list, versus just removing them from the parent.

I'm still curious why after doing a remove() on the parent using the JoinColumns was causing a null update. I have a few other entities that are doing the same thing but for now just simpler to either use a delete statement, or create a new ID column and move away from all the multifield IDs and JoinColumns the code currently has.